# Upload to s3 from react-native CameraRoll

Tags: ios, file-upload, amazon-s3, react-native, camera-roll

Considering using [react-native-uploader](https://github.com/aroth/react-native-uploader) to upload from iOS CameraRoll to s3. My end goal is to allow users to select an image from CameraRoll and post it on an api-based chat (sendbird). Based on the documentation, for `react-native-uploader`, though, it doesn't seem like it returns the s3 url in the response. Does anyone know if there's a way to get this back in the response? Perhaps I be approaching another way entirely?

Part of the rationale for this approach is that it's similar to how it works when a file is uploaded on the web-based version of the chat. We use file-uploader, then we post the message to sendbird using the s3 version of the url. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using [`react-native-aws3`](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3) instead. It was very straight forward.